# Xmas ham on the BBQ

Tags: barbecue

We are hosting Xmas for the first time this year, and our oven is going to be full with turkey and vegetables, so I am hoping to do the ham (half a leg) on the BBQ (with lid down)

Is this a feasible plan, and does anyone have any suggestions on how should I do it?

(I hope this is not contravening any 'no recipes' rule, I'm really looking for some pointers on not destroying the ham and stressing out my already stressed wife further :) )

Comment: I noticed you're from Sydney, do you mean glazing and warming through a cooked ham (which seems the most common in Australia) or cooking raw ham from scratch?

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks for replying, I only just noticed, apologies for not acknowledging it earlier. Yes, it was a cooked leg ham. For the record, I scored the fat, added cloves and glazed it in a honey, maple syrup, Dijon and brown sugar mix. I found a burner combination, on the BBQ, that stabilised around 180c (though I started it higher to crisp the fat), then cooked it for about an hour (re-glazing every 20 minutes). It came out brilliantly, and we are still enjoying the leftovers (stored in a vinegar soaked pillow case in the fridge). Will definitely do it again.